# sed: -e expression #1, char 27: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Tags: linux, sed

```
echo $variable = {"name":"AAA","username":"BBB"}
```

I would like to filter only `BBB` from above output. I have used this sed command:

```
sed 's/."username":"(["])".*/\1/')
```

I am getting

> sed: -e expression #1, char 27: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should use a JSON parser such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse JSON: `jq -r '.username' <<< "$variable"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches just the BBB part. Escape your parens.
Assuming this is JSON, there won't be any quotes in the value you're looking for (since it's quote-delimited) so I matched the BBB part with [^"]* which is any number of characters that aren't quotes.

```
variable='{"name":"AAA","username":"BBB"}'
echo "$variable" |sed 's/.*"username":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
```